# How to redirect url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I redirect below in htaccess

```
url/api/login?status_check=1   ->   `url/stack/api/login.php?status_check=1`
url/u/123456789 -> `url/stack/user/show_profile.php?uid=123456789`
```

Comment: @TaraWilfred Adding [tag:php] does not help. The question has nothing to do with php.

Comment: Sorry, I mean how to can write valid htaccess langues to achieve that? For example in my question I wanted to redirect when users access "http://url/u/123456789" and they are actually visiting "http://url/stack/user/show_profile.php?uid=123456789"

Comment: Search for similar questions on [so]. You'll find that it isn't that difficult. You have to show what you tried to solve your problem, and not just ask for solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I will do more research and tries tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys I post here because comments dont provide ability of posting codes. If anyone feels offended, I apologize.
I now get my url redirect working on local environment such as http://localhost/api/signup but it displays an error of 404 when I uploaded to the server as http://server.com/api/signup

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
Options -Indexes
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/signup stack/api/api.signup.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^api/signin stack/api/api.signin.php [NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I found the solution of this issue by enabled the mod_rewrite on the server and added AllowOverride All in the Apache config.